# what does "virtual" mean here and why? or what is its concept here?

Tags: vocabulary

I am wondering what is the concept of the bold part here? although I know what it means.
 Meanwhile, would you please show me what is the difference in meaning between the italic part and A-- my revised?

A. old and new friends

Social networking is an important part of many people's lives now where massive numbers of people congregate on sites like Facebook and interact with *friends old and new*, real and **virtual**.

...........

Thanks. I cannot yet get what is the difference between the following conceptually, or how do they differ from each other here?
 old/ new/ real / virtual

[enter link description here](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/it-moral-values/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *virtual* friend in this situation might be a Facebook friend who you have never met. Although they are a real person, for all intents and purposes they might as well be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

*Virtual* there means "simulated, not flesh-and-blood", such as role-playing personae.

After reading further, I see that they're using the word *virtual* as a synonym for "online", which is an invalid use in my opinion. A pen-pal is not a virtual friend, so why should an online acquaintance be considered virtual?

Answer (score 0):

**Real** refers to things in the physical world, whereas **virtual** refers to things that exist on the internet. It's one of the words used to differentiate what you "have," or simply have access to, in your online universe as opposed to the things in your actual world.

Another way of expressing this is with the prefix **cyber**-, for example some people have lots of *cyber*-friends, but few *real* friends.

Finally, you can simply use **online** as an adjective: I have more *online* dictionaries than I do *real* dictionaries.